# Does Selenium's waitForpageToLoad function always wait the full time?

Tags: selenium

Does waitForPageToLoad wait for the full time specified or return sooner if the page gets loaded?

For example:

```
$this->waitForPageToLoad("6000");
```

Does this load after 6 seconds always, or sooner if the page loads in 1 second?

Answer (score 2):

It returns sooner.  The argument is a timeout, a period after which to abort waiting for the page to load.

Answer (score 1):

It should return before that time if the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The argument you are passing, is the maximum time duration as per your expectation. If the page is loaded before it, it returns back to execute next command. if not then it will show the error msg